# Python 3.6 regex match unexpected results

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am using a simple regex to try and classify strings as either relating to entitlements (wages) or other.

I have tested the regex in regex101.com and it seems to work as expected but when I run the code I get some strange results

```
import re

wages_regx = re.compile(r" pay | payment | salary | salaries | wages? | rates? | hourly rates? | allowances? | penalties | penalty | overtime | under payments? | over payments? | entitlements? ", re.I)

def classify(string):
    if wages_regx.match(string):
        return 'Entitlements'
    else:
        return 'Other'
```

Tests

```
classify('I have an question about my wages rate.') 
# Returns: Other (Should return Entitlements) should match on (wages? and rates?)

classify(' wages ') 
# Returns Entitlements as expected

classify('ras wages c') 
# Returns Other (Should return Entitlements)

classify(' wages c') 
# Returns Entitlements as expected
```

Comment: you want `.search` not `.match`

Comment: @AnthonySottile - yep... derp... cheers